# Acer anbmServ using 99% CPU - how can I disable this service?

Tags: windows, services

I ran `msconfig`, but it doesn't list this service under either the *Services* tab or the *Startup* tab.  I found multiple references to the service in the registry, but am not sure which one to edit to stop this service running.

I have checked an number of sites, and they all say that the service is not necessary, and I have killed it a number of times without and drastic side effects.  I just want to know how to disable it permanently.

Comment: If yuo can easily kill it, then it's probably not a service but rather a normal program running under your user account. You might find it in the usual places for automatically starting programs.

Comment: No, it is running under `SYSTEM` - I don't know why I could easily kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Start->Run and typing in services.msc. Find anbmServ in the list and click Stop, to stop it immediately, and the set it to "Manual" so that it won't start up at boot-up.

I hope this helps - I did this from memory from my OS X machine...

Update: you can also use [CodeStuff's Starter](http://codestuff.tripod.com/products_starter.html) to see what runs during your system's startup: services and executables.

Answer (score 1):

The executable `anbmserv.exe` is part of the [software bundled with Acer notebooks](http://www.acerpanam.com/synapse/forms/webpage.cfm?website=AcerPanAm.com&siteid=7117&areaid=2&id=8) and adds additional diagnostics and power management features to this range of hardware.

If you don't need these diagnostic software (I normally remove many of these extra programs computer manufactures add to your system), try to uninstall it from the Control Panel, it should be listed there.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (written by Mark Russinovich, working at Microsoft now) to stop Services and other programs from starting up automatically...
It has the benefit, that it shows all startup items not only those in the services department.